# Is it possible to execute a JavaScript file in a chrome packaged app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, box2d, eval, google-chrome-app

I am trying to make a Box2D TestBed structure in a Chrome app using [kripken's Box2D.js](https://github.com/kripken/box2d.js). I have successfully gotten the testbed built and working [you can download it from here](https://github.com/caffinatedmonkey/Box2D-TestBed). One of the features I would like to add to the testbed is the ability to load JavaScript files at runtime. Since chrome apps can't use `eval` is there any way of loading a JavaScript file at runtime? I've tried using `$.getScript` with a `file:///` URL and the appropriate permissions but that doesn't work. [Here are some example files that I would like to load at runtime.](https://github.com/caffinatedmonkey/Box2D-TestBed/tree/master/tests) This is very frustrating since the program can be run on the web but not in a chrome app!

#### UPDATE:

I've tried using a chrome sandbox to do the evaling but I cannot pass functions through `window.postMessage`. I'm beginning to lean towards hosting it on a server.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that whichever technical solution you come up with, if you want to upload your app to the Chrome Web Store, you'll have to comply with the TOS, which says that apps must not "download or execute scripts dynamically outside a sandboxed environment such as a webview or a sandboxed iframe." In other words, kzahel's answer is the right way to go, both technically and contractually. See https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/program_policies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to load external scripts. There's a catch though; you'll have to do it in a sandboxed page that doesn't have any access to the chrome.* APIs. But you can communicate with this page through window.postMessage

See http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external.html

Comment: This won't work because I need a JavaScript object not a string.`postMessage` would give me a string, Right?

Comment: chrome lets you pass not only objects but typed arrays, and at that, the ability to use transferable objects (preventing a copy)

Comment: I'll try it and check back.

Comment: I know I can send messages from me->sandbox but how can I send messages from sandbox->me I also can't seem to send an object containing a function I get `DataCloneError: An object could not be cloned.` This won't work.

Comment: You can't really send a function through postMessage, but you can call .toString() on the function, however it won't contain any of its scope, etc. You probably shouldn't need to pass around a function anyway. You probably should "register" a callback with a string identifier and have the sandbox respond using that identifier so that the "me" knows how to use the response. The sandbox can respond using window.postMessage and "me" can listen for it using addEventListener('message',...)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up dumping the whole testbed in a sandbox.